# UI Button.onClick handling multiple buttons via script

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, event-handling, game-engine

I'm loading and instantiating a Unity prefab that has UI objects in it (text, buttons) and want to assign the `onClick` handler for each found button via script ...

```
GameObject uiObj = ResourceUtil.InstantiatePrefab("Prefabs/UI/Main Menu UI", "UI");
uiObj.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform, false);
Button[] buttons = uiObj.GetComponentsInChildren<Button>();
foreach (Button button in buttons)
{
    button.onClick.AddListener(() => OnUIButtonClick(button.name)); 
}

public void OnUIButtonClick(string buttonID)
{
    Log.Debug("OnUIButtonClick: " + buttonID);
}
```

However when clicking any of the buttons, only the ID of the last button is ever logged out. It seems that every button receives the same onClick handler assignment (which is the last in the iteration). How can I get it to work so that the onClick handler is assigned uniquely to every button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue. I still do not fully understand why did it start working, probably it was some addressing issue on lower level or something, but solution was something like:

```
foreach (Button button in buttons)
{
    string _name = button.name;
    button.onClick.AddListener(() => OnUIButtonClick(_name)); 
}
```

Comment: Interesting! This works, thanks. Another way I found meanwhile is to use `EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.name` but I prefer to get the ID from the buttons directly instead.

Comment: Quite right, this is a weird misunderstanding or something in Unity -- indeed, there are a number of questions about it here. Nobody has really explained it well.